# Any way to handle replacement of unknown value components

Tags: identification

i have a board here ms-16751 ver1.3. The pwr connector has been pushed in and took with it two inductors and a cap located directly behind it. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how could i determine safe values of the components i could replace the missing ones with. Scoured the web in search of schematics but no joy. Cheers [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-engineering the circuit is a potential step. Look the traces and for identifiable ICs and reference designs of said ICs to see if you can find a similar topology on your PCB. If you know the application of your circuit and can determine the function of the components, then it's possible to determine how sensitive the circuit will be to the component value.

Naturally, this isn't particularly easy for us without access to the actual PCB and some diagnostic tools, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense, i'll do just that. Very helpful answer. cheers